# Checking for discontinuities

Tags: functions, conditional, discontinuity

There was an older post about checking the continuity of a function but the routines in the reply don't seem to work for my function. Hence the new post.
If I have a function

```
If[x<0,x+1,x^2+2]
```

can Mathematica spit out where the discontinuity is?
TIA!

Comment: Prior to v12.2, the most likely place to look is at the transition point: `Equal @@ (Limit[f[x], x -> 0, Direction -> #] & /@ {"FromBelow", "FromAbove"})`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Better is convert `If` function to `Piecewise`.`FunctionDiscontinuities` works only on `MMA 12.2.0`.You can execute this function on [Wolfram Cloud.](https://develop.wolframcloud.com),you must only **sign in**.

```
FunctionDiscontinuities[Piecewise[{{x + 1, x < 0}}, x^2 + 2], x]
(*x==0*)
```

For more info see [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionDiscontinuities.html).

Of course `FunctionDiscontinuities[If[x < 0, x + 1, x^2 + 2], x]` works too,but give some `errors`.

Comment: Just to add, `PiecewiseExpand[If[x < 0, x + 1, x^2 + 2]]` will do the required conversion on your behalf.

Comment: @J.M.'sdiscontentment .Oh yes thanks.

Comment: This works, thanks. But is there a way to execute the same in Mathematica 12.0?

Comment: @123infinity no, only works on MMA 12.2.0 or higher.

Answer (score 3):

`` FunctionProperties`Singularities `` has been around for a while and works in V12.0, which [the OP seemed once to want](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/237113/checking-for-discontinuities#comment598800_237114). It's undocumented, and I don't know how to fully explain.  It returns discontinuities in the form `{equation, condition}`. (This is an acceptable syntax to pass to the `Exclusions` option of many solvers.)

```
disc = FunctionProperties`Singularities[
  If[x < 0, x + 1, x^2 + 2],
  {x},
  {"BRANCHCUTS", "DEFCUTS", 
   "POLES", "ESSENTIAL", "IGNORE", "PWMINMAX"}]

(*  {{}, {{-x == 0, True}, {x == 0, True}}, {}, {}, {}}  *)

DeleteDuplicates[
 Join @@ Simplify[disc]
 ]

(*  {{x == 0, True}}  *)
```

It handles multivariate functions as well:

```
FunctionProperties`Singularities[
 Log[x - y], {x, y}, {"BRANCHCUTS", "DEFCUTS", "POLES", "ESSENTIAL", 
  "IGNORE", "PWMINMAX"}]

(*  {{{Im[x - y] == 0, Re[x - y] <= 0}}, {}, {}, {}, {}}  *)
```